# How to export my Kruskal wallace pairwise test to a table from R?

Tags: r, statistics, export-to-csv

I am trying to export my statistical results as a table from R. But because it is in a `list` format I can't change it to a dataframe to be exported. Here is a sample of my dataframe

```
df = structure(list(Method_Group = c("Animal Borne + No Receiver", 
"Animal Borne + No Receiver", "Animal Borne + No Receiver", "Animal Borne + No Receiver", 
"Animal Borne + No Receiver", "Animal Borne + Receiver", "Animal Borne + Receiver", 
"Animal Borne + Receiver", "Animal Borne + Receiver", "BRUV + Both", 
"BRUV + Both", "BRUV + Both", "BRUV + Both", "BRUV + Receiver", 
"BRUV + Receiver", "BRUV + Receiver", "BRUV + Receiver", "BRUV + Receiver", 
"BRUV + Receiver", "Controlled + No Receiver", "Controlled + No Receiver", 
"Controlled + Receiver", "Controlled + Receiver", "Controlled + Receiver", 
"Controlled + Receiver", "Controlled + Receiver", "Controlled + Receiver", 
"Stationary + No Receiver", "Stationary + No Receiver", "Stationary + No Receiver", 
"Stationary + No Receiver", "Stationary + No Receiver", "Stationary + No Receiver", 
"Stationary + Receiver", "Stationary + Receiver", "Stationary + Receiver", 
"Stationary + Receiver", "Stationary + Receiver", "Stationary + Receiver", 
"Stationary + Receiver"), Topic = c("Behavioural Ecology", "Conservation Methods", 
"Methodological", "Other Drivers", "Reproductive Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", 
"Methodological", "Other Drivers", "Reproductive Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", 
"Conservation Methods", "Methodological", "Other Drivers", "Behavioural Ecology", 
"Conservation Methods", "Fisheries Managemenet", "Methodological", 
"Other Drivers", "Reproductive Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", 
"Methodological", "Behavioural Ecology", "Conservation Methods", 
"Fisheries Managemenet", "Methodological", "Other Drivers", "Reproductive Ecology", 
"Behavioural Ecology", "Fisheries Managemenet", "Landuse Management", 
"Methodological", "Other Drivers", "Reproductive Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", 
"Conservation Methods", "Fisheries Managemenet", "Landuse Management", 
"Methodological", "Other Drivers", "Reproductive Ecology"), Total = c(19L, 
3L, 13L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 
2L, 21L, 2L, 8L, 5L, 17L, 6L, 7L)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -40L))
```

These are the tests I'm running

```
Res = kruskal.test(Total ~ Method_Group, data=df)
Res

table = pairwise.wilcox.test(df$Total, df$Method_Group,
                     p.adjust.method = "BH")
```

And obviously this code below isn't working to export it

```
table = as.data.frame(table)
write.csv(table, file.path("PairwiseWilcox.csv", sep = ""))
```

Any ideas how to export these results as a csv table?

Comment: You don't need the `as.data.frame` - you can just do `table |> broom::tidy() |> readr::write_csv('table.csv')`

Comment: See what  `pairwise.wilcox.test(df$Total, df$Method_Group, p.adjust.method = "BH")$p.value` does for you. Also, make sure you read the warnings.

Comment: @IanCampbell I did look at the warnings, but when I look them up it appears to be normal for this test. Am I wrong?